# Asynchronous SR DFF positive edge triggered [CMOS, SPICE]

Tags: mosfet, ltspice, flipflop, cmos, spice

I have been following some reference designs from Texas Instruments and Nexperia, and have been trying to replicate a model in LTspice (I am aware of the one in LTspice's library, but I would like have one that I can study myself).

My issue is that it is dual-edge triggered rather than being positive-edge triggered, changing the rise and fall times of the clock signals can generate a really glitched positive edge response. I've attached a link and an image of the schematic, so if anyone could provide any guidance that would be great.

Parameters for transistors: default LTSPICE PMOS4 and NMOS4 specs

[image: Design]

[image]

Trial and error timings:
[image]

Comment: Link to asc file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/13tVKJZeYWT4zMOeWBGuvmqoWzoHLr73P/view?usp=share_link

Comment: I presume you're replicating a circuit that's inside of a CMOS integrated circuit. For that, the spice model should be using NMOS and PMOS devices with channel resistance and size at least in the same ballpark as used in the semiconductor process you're mimicking. What are the parameters of the NMOS and PMOS you're using in the schematic? It'd help to add that info to the question (edit it), so that it's not necessary to download the .asc file.

Comment: You are correctly using `nmos4` and `pmos4` symbols, but you need to right-click each of them and set their `L`, `W`, and possibly also the `AD` and `AS` parameters to fulfill the design properly.  ALSO, you need to connect the body terminals of the PMOS transistors to VDD and the body terminals of the NMOS transistors to VSS (or GND in this case).  Finally, you need to define "modelcards" (i.e. `.model` statements) for your transistors so you can set at least the `Vto` and `Kp` parameters for your MOSFETs.

Comment: So currently I've been using the standard parameters for the NMOS4 and PMOS4 (the ones the LTSPICE defaults to). So previously my designs for a latch, adder and subtractor all worked fine with no timing or glitch issues. As most of my assembly ready designs have already been completed I'm a bit hesitant to go back to change all of the parameters so have been stuck with trying to figure the timings or identify an error with the design

Comment: I managed to get a semi working, albiet glitched positive edge triggered response. I messed around with the timings a bit, but was wondering why this circuit was more sensitive to timings than another positive edge triggered DFF without SR inputs.

Comment: There's no such thing as a MOSFET with a `Vto` of zero volts, which is what the default models use (see built-in LTspice help).  Hard to answer your question exactly, but that would be the first place I would look.  Also, like I said, the body terminals on an actual CMOS chip aren't shorted to each MOSFET's source terminals, but tied to the most positive (PMOS) and most negative (NMOS) rails of the chip.  That would be the 2nd place I would look.  I would check out cmosedu.com where they provide proper SPICE models for a 1um and 50nm process. https://cmosedu.com/cmos1/cmosedu_models.txt

Comment: Also, the textbook "Microelectronic Circuits by Sedra/Smith" has 5um and 0.5um process model definitions.  Their student resources website has it within a ZIP file listed under "SPICE Netlists Appendix B": https://learninglink.oup.com/access/sedra8e-student-resources

Comment: @SteKulov Just wanted to point out that a Vto of zero volts or lower is possible, but not standard (and not really advised for CMOS logic circuits like this one).

Comment: @SvenB  True.  Good point.  I should've been more specific.  Thanks!

Comment: @SteKulov and SvenB Thanks for the pointers! I'll check them out in the next few days. Though was curious why this circuit requires more specifications than a DFF without SR inputs (my previous design for a DFF all used generic LTSpice ones), unless there's an alternative CMOS implementation for this SR DFF Positive Edge Triggered circuit?

Comment: Like I said before, there's no easy answer and you have to go do the troubleshooting yourself.  I gave you a few places to start looking.  Another place would be that the default models have all capacitive effects set to zero, so anything requiring feedback will not function properly without a stabilizing RC network.  Usually this network is formed via the parasitic components...but they are all set to zero if you're using default models.  Put another way, many of these digital CMOS circuits require non-idealities to function properly and the default models try to be as ideal as possible.